# If else not working because it contains end within

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a a helper that contains a simple on and off switch. I know I have it working because it's working on other pages. However, on this particular page it won't work.. I think its because theres an `end` within the if else, so it ends the if else early. Here's the code:

I believe this part is working:

```
<% if popup == "off" %>
       <% content_for :main do %>
<% end %>
```

This part not so much:

```
<% if popup == "off" %>
       <% end %>  << this end should be displayed if popup = off 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you trying to display the word end? You would want to use
 what Russel said for that

Comment: @spike.. No i want to display <% end %>

Comment: Rather `<%= "<% end %>" %>`(note the quotes around `end`).

Comment: Yea, made a typo. I think you'll need <%= '<% end %>' %> then, but maybe someone knows a cleaner way

Comment: @Jonah You should try to clarify your question, each anwserer looks more confused than the other ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems all the suggestions of doing `<%= "<% end %>" %>` results in a syntax error.. May seem like easy way out by ended up just restructuring my app and got rid of the requirement of `<% content_for :main do %>`

Comment: Try the second solution of spike then, it should solve your problem.

Comment: I think the cause may be the helper isnt being loaded properly. Regardless, it was about time i got right of the content_for :main anyway, long overdo. Sorry for wasting youe time!

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
<% if popup == "off" %>
       <%= "<% end %>" %>  << this end should be displayed if popup = off 
<% end %>
```

or try this:

```
<% if popup == "off" %>
       &lt;% end %&gt;  << this end should be displayed if popup = off 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the word `end` to be displayed, don't enclose it in tags. Anything enclosed in tags is interpreted as Ruby code, anything not is printed exactly as it is.

```
<% if popup == "off" %>
   end  << this will now be interpreted as text, not ruby code
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

ERB (and Ruby) doesn't work like that.

I think you're treating it like you are trying to end an HTML tag instead of an `end` to a Ruby block, and that you want everything in between those two code segments to run in the `content_for` block.

Here's what you need. Everything in between will be included in the `content_for` block:

```
<% if popup == "off" %>
  <% content_for :main do %>
    your block code will be evaluated here.
  <% end %>  
<% end %>
```